# More efficient way to one hot encode array?

Tags: python

First time poster here, I have some arrays (~25k) which for the most part look like the "Original Map" below. I would like to separate each of them into their components based on their values (kind of like separating into RGB from grayscale) which would give me three maps as shown below:

```
# Original Map:
# 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 0 0
# 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 0
# 0 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 0 0
# 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

# First component[0,;,;,0]   Second component[0,;,;,1] Last component[0,;,;,2]
# (Padding)                   (Good Die)                (Bad Die)

# 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1        # 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1        # 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0    # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1        # 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0    # 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1        # 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0    # 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1        # 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0    # 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1        # 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0    # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1        # 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0    # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1        # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    # 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is the code I'm using (see below), however, its painfully inefficient and when I have to run this through 25,000 maps I run out of RAM and can't actually do it. Is there a better way?

```
reshaped = np.zeros((1,map_exm.shape[0], map_exm.shape[1], 3))
for h in range(map_exm.shape[0]):
  for w in range(map_exm.shape[1]):
    reshaped[0,h, w, map_exm[h][w]] = 1
```

PS: I've tried doing it on a subset of maps and then just appending each result to the final partitioned maps, but thought that was more a workaround than a real solution, perhaps there's a more efficient way to actually partition the arrays.

Edit: I think it's a better description to say I'm trying to one hot encode my arrays so i changed the title of my question. I'm doing this to feed them into a CNN for training.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to create an array with a one-hot encoded channel from an array of integers? How the results going to be used?

Comment: See my edit, but I'm going to feed it as training data for a CNN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a quick 1 liner:

```
np.array([(map_exm == i).astype(int) for i in range(3)]).transpose((1,2,0))[None]
```

`transpose((1,2,0))` re-orders the axes and `[None]` creates the extra axis at the front to get the same result / shape as yours.

or even simpler as suggested in comment below:

```
(map_exm[None, ..., None] == range(3)).astype(int)
```

although seems a tad slower:

```
import timeit

%timeit np.array([(map_exm == i).astype(int) for i in range(3)]).transpose((1,2,0))[None]
# 3.81 µs ± 7.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit (map_exm[None, ..., None] == range(3)).astype(int)
# 5.05 µs ± 416 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `map_exm[..., np.newaxis] == range(3)` accomplish the same? But this still doesn't address the "when I have to run this through 25,000 maps I run out of RAM" problem.

Comment: Sure but then we need either more info on how this is to be used, or the answer is just buy more RAM...

Comment: Thanks this definitely helped optimize my code and perhaps even made it a bit quicker, I still have the issue of RAM though that I'll try to figure out later.

Comment: I figured out the ram issue, I used generators to train my CNN which saved a ton of memory. Thanks again stack community!

Answer (score 1):

As usual with numpy, use broadcasting, for speed.

We can do this by asking where the original array
is equal to each desired component value.

```
import numpy as np

original = map_exm
assert original.shape == (1, 8, 10)

for val in range(3):
    print(f"\n{val}")
    print(np.array(original == val, dtype=np.uint8))
```

Storing bytes rather than 64-bit ints will save you *some* room.

But still, you might want to re-evaluate whether you want
expansions of 25k original images to be RAM-resident all at once.
It's simple enough to expand each one as needed,
or to store those expansions externally, perhaps
in a filesystem or even in a database.

---

nit: Rather than

```
reshaped_images_test = np.zeros((1, map_exm.shape[0], map_exm.shape[1], 3))
```

this would suffice.

```
reshaped_images_test = np.zeros((1, *map_exm.shape, 3))
```